# AsyncFileUploadWithAjaxToolKit not worked

Tags: asp.net

Hi to all I'd using the following code for upload :

```
HTML:
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" runat="server"
            OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
            OnClientUploadStarted="StartUpload"
            OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete"
            CompleteBackColor="Lime" UploaderStyle="Modern"
            ErrorBackColor="Red"
            ThrobberID="Throbber"
            OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete"
            UploadingBackColor="#66CCFF" />

        <asp:Label ID="Throbber" runat="server" Style="display: none">
        <img src="Images/indicator.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="loading" />
        </asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Style="font-family: Arial; font-size: small;"></asp:Label>
```

And my java script code is:

```
 function uploadError(sender, args) {
        document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = args.get_fileName(), "<span style='color:red;'>" + args.get_errorMessage() + "</span>";
    }

    function StartUpload(sender, args) {
        document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = 'Uploading Started.';
    }

    function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var filename = args.get_fileName();
        var contentType = args.get_contentType();
        var text = "Size of " + filename + " is " + args.get_length() + " bytes";
        if (contentType.length > 0) {
            text += " and content type is '" + contentType + "'.";
        }
        document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = text;
    }
```

And my server Slide scripting :

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string strPath = MapPath("~/Uploads/") + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
            AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(strPath);
        }

    }
```

and I've the folowing error:

> > Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js Failed to
> >     load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> >     Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax
> >     client-side framework failed to load. test.aspx:72 Uncaught
> >     ReferenceError: Sys is not defined test.aspx:84 Uncaught
> >     ReferenceError: Sys is not defined test.aspx:105 Uncaught
> >     ReferenceError: Sys is not defined

It my first time to using this conrotl plz help me thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you included the ClientScriptManager control?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the ScriptManager with EnablePageMethods="true" attribute for this to work

eg:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```